# How can i get the values of the list bounded to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have bound a list to a `DataGrid`. After modifying the list in the `DataGrid` I'd like to save the list in a xml file. how can I get access to the list in the c# code?
In other words I wanna get the content of Welle1 after clicking on a `Button`.

````cs
InitializeComponent();

List<Wellenelement> we1 = new List<Wellenelement>();
Welle Welle1 = new Welle
            {
                Elemente = we1
            };

dataGrid.DataContext = Welle1;

```c#
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, using WPF, you'll have to make use of Properties and the PropertyChangedEvent.

Go to your MainWindow.xaml.cs (or to your ViewModel, if you already use MVVM) and add beneath your Constructor (usually `public MainWindow(){ //[...]` )

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
  {
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

you'll also have to add `using System.ComponentModel;` to your usings to find the required classes.

Next you add a new `Property` right above your Constructor like this:

```
  private ObservableCollection<WellenElement> m_WellenListe;
  public ObservableCollection<WellenElement> WellenListe
    {
      get { return m_WellenListe; }
      set
      {
        m_WellenListe = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("WellenListe");
      }
    }
```

Note: I'll suggest using an `ObservableCollection` over a `List`, if you want to change your ItemsSource at runtime. (You have to add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` to get the class)

Now you can bind your `DataGrid` to your `ObservableCollection`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding WellenListe}"/>
```

Now you can do whatever you want with your List in code behind like:

```
button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(WellenElement welle in WellenListe)
    {
      //Save to xml
    }

}
```

Comment: What if i want to have 2 datagrids bound to 2 different instances of my class Welle? e.g. Welle1 and Welle  to bound to datagrid1, datagrid2 respectively.  Can i bind to differnet datagrids to 1 property and use to different instances of it?

Comment: let's be a little more clear first: what is your class 'Welle'? Are there 2 files (one .xaml and one .xaml.cs) or is there only one ( .cs) file?